# Flutter circular_countdown_timer time restarts when pushing to screen

Tags: flutter, timer, restart

I'am using the circular_countdown_timer package from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_countdown_timer) everytime i leave the screen that has the countdown_timer and push back to the screen the timer restarts from 0, is there a way to save the timer state ?

And this is my code:

```
CircularCountDownTimer(
                     duration: 10,
                     initialDuration: 0,
                     controller: CountDownController(),
                     width: 55.0,
                     height: 85.0,
                     ringColor:
                     Color(0x30A6CA).withOpacity(0.1),
                     ringGradient: null,
                     fillColor: Color(0xFF30A6CA),
                     fillGradient: null,
                     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                     backgroundGradient: null,
                     strokeWidth: 10.0,
                     strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
                     textStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                     fontSize: 14.0,
                     color: Colors.black,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                     ),
                     textFormat: CountdownTextFormat.MM_SS,
                     isReverse: true,
                     isReverseAnimation: false,
                     isTimerTextShown: true,
                     autoStart: true,
                     onStart: () {},
                     onComplete: () {},
                     ),
```